# NullPointerException when set a custom font on a TextView

Tags: android, fonts, nullpointerexception, textview

I'm trying to use a custom font on a TextView... but i got that exception when when run my app

```
 
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface)' on a null object reference
```

in the right path and that's my code:

[image]

My XML 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Problem is not connected with your custom font - it is connected with TextView.

You are not inflating layout to HomeActivity. Missing part:

```
setContentView(R.layout.your_home_activity_layout)
```

Put it between lines `protected void onCreate()` and `SetFont usfnt1`

Comment: can u pls  check this image  http://i.imgur.com/ilcN9XI.png

Comment: @Freeman `super.onCreate(paramBundle) setContentView(R.layout.activity_home)` should be placed before findviewbyid. You are trying to find view when layout is not inflated.

Comment: u save my day  thankies

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting your content view? Add the follow in your onCreate()

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
```

Comment: yes i did http://i.imgur.com/ilcN9XI.png

Comment: Have you tried using a different font, or even an .otf file instead?